# How do I run python 3.4 on sublime text 2?

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

This is what my python build looks like:

```
{  
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],  
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",  
    "selector": "source.python"    
}
```

I've read that I need to change what's in the "python" part of "cmd":, but I can't find what to change it to. I've [seen one video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZpuwW-9T54) where a guy made it look really easy by taking the path from the terminal. Others say to add a "path": blah blah blah. It always seems to be for Windows computers.

I've tried so many things and I really don't know what to change to make sublime text 2 to run python. Also does it make a difference if I'm using a mac vs windows?

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe that comment was made before the OP edited the question and title to indicate he wanted to run Py3.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd` needs to be changed to the path of the python 3 executable. By default, the installer places it in `~/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3`. So, if your mac username is `Anthony`, you will need to change your build like so:

```
{  
    "cmd": ["/Users/Anthony/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],  
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",  
    "selector": "source.python"    
}
```

**Note:** When running python 3 from the terminal, you are able to use the shortcut command `python3`. This is because an ALIAS was set up in your .bash_profile when python was installed. However, Sublime Text doesn't read your .bash_profile, so you must specify the full path to python.